# How do I handle OperationCanceledException in ASP.NET Web APIs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, parallel-processing

I have this simple controller, whose `Get` method is called with ajax to look up zipcodes via an Entity Framework repository.

```
[Authorize]
public class ZipCodesApiController : AppApiController
{
    public ZipCode Get(string zipCode)
    {
        return unitOfWork.ZipCodeRepository
            .Get(x => x.Zip == zipCode)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

In production, my logs show that `System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.` is thrown quite often. I think what's going on is that users are viewing an address detail page, but navigating away or closing their browser before the ajax zipcode lookup returns. I guess IIS is telling my controller that they are no longer connected, and the .NET framework throws an exception?

This seems harmless, but it also seems like a bad idea to wrap the call to ZipCodeRepository in a `try` and have an empty `OperationCanceledException` catch clause.

I've googled the error and it seems to come up quite a bit in parallel programming, which is not something I am particularly familiar with.

**What is an appropriate way to handle this exception?** I think it's safe to ignore, but am I wrong about that, and the Entity Framework should be alerted so that it can clean something up (my AppApiController does have a dispose method at least)?

Comment: Just FYI...not an answer to your question, but in latest version of Web API, if you have an action defined like this `public async Task<ZipCode> Get(string zipCode, CancellationToken token)`, you can register for the token cancellation and this would be called in situations where the client disconnects.

Comment: if you are using other async APIs downstream it would be good to pass on this cancellation token so that you can give them a chance to cleanup any stuff if they might want to

Answer (score 3):

I get the same exceptions in my web API application, however i can catch them with the Application_Error method in Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
        Response.Clear();
        OperationCanceledException httpException = exception as OperationCanceledException;
        if (httpException != null)
        {
            var token = httpException.CancellationToken;
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // clear error on server
                Server.ClearError();
                Request.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know if that is right.